# ReportRequest not like in Telegram Api

Tags: python, telethon

Why `ReportRequest` ask messages? In telegram API no parameter message, I don't want to send a message in the report, how do I do this?? and `ReportPeerRequest` too ask message. why?

Comment: Here you're wrong. The methods are generates from the telegram schema and if something exists there, also exists on telethon generated methods: https://schema.horner.tj/#!/method/messages.report

Comment: And referring to the message you can leave it empty and it should work